# How to add watermark image properly fit XY on video using ffpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, watermark, android-ffmpeg, video-watermarking

I am trying to add following watermark image on video using ffpeg but it doesnt fit properly.

[Watermark Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6DLUr.png)

Following is my FFmpeg commond :

> > String[] complexCommand = {"-i", AppUtils.videoPath, "-i",
> >     framelocalPath ,  "-preset", "ultrafast", "-filter_complex",
> >     "overlay=(W-w)/2:(H-h)/2" , dest1.getAbsolutePath()};

But it doesnt fit properly on video, following is my output :

[Here is my video with watermark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2EpG.jpg)

If anybody can help for `overlay` with `FFmpeg`. I also tried different solutions but doesnt help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the ffmpeg command you should run,

```
ffmpeg -i video -i image -filter_complex "[1][0]scale2ref[img][vid];[vid][img]overlay" -preset ultrafast out.mp4
```

The scale2ref filter resizes the image to match the dimensions of the video. The overlay can then occur at (0,0).

Comment: Hello @Gyan, Thank you for your reply. Let me check.

Comment: Its working perfectly, Thank you so much for your help :)